# how to get the name of a file without knowing his path C# app

Tags: c#

I am building an application in c# and i need 
to get the name of a file without knowing his path (browser) (not a web app not asp),
so later i could change his name.
how can i do that

thanks for all the help

Comment: So, if you dont know the name, and you dont know the path....how do you know what you are looking for?

Comment: Wait a minute... Where is your app running? Is this server code? Are you writing a browser plugin of some sort? And more importantly, how do you know what you're looking for?

Comment: no, i do not know the file name, i want to open a window that show me all my files and i will Select the file i want, and i just want to change his name not his executable end

Comment: accessing file with no name or path, you ought to do something magical!

Comment: please add some more detail about  what exactly you are trying to do, so that we can tell you what could be done!

Comment: sorry, can you give a more detailed example of what you are giong to do, where the file is (server/client) what kind of application you are creating and what name you are giong to change (name in a database, file name on disk, ...?)

Comment: Just use this `const string FILE_NAME = @"c:\funky_business\zebra.jpg";` and you won't need any code to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I assume you are using [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) to

> "show me all my files and i will
>   Select the file i want"

You can get the file name (path) of the file you have selected using OpenFileDialog's `FileName` property. To get only file name + extension use the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class function `GetFileName()`.
Here is some code

```
using (OpenFileDialog dg = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            if (dg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string path = dg.FileName;
                string name = Path.GetFileName(path); 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming from your comments that you want to open a file browsing dialog, then it depends upon which framework you are using.

If you are using Forms, then you can use the Forms [FileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.aspx).

If you are using WPF, then you can use the Win32 [OpenFileDialog](http://blog.davidsandor.com/post/How-to-use-the-Open-File-Dialog-in-WPF.aspx).

As I recall, these dialogs will probably let you rename files directly within them (e.g. select the file and hit F2).